# Date for the previous day @ 4am

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

Given a Date, I'd like to get a Date at 4:00. This fails for 0:00 - 3:39:

```
let date3am = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 7, day: 1, hour: 3, minute: 0, second: 0))!

let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0, of: 
date3am, direction: .backward)!

date // "Jul 1, 2017, 4:00 AM"
date < date3am // false
```

Why does `date(bySettingHour)` not go backwards?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. I think you have an arbitrary date (e.g. `date3am`) and you're trying to obtain the date at 04:00 of that _same day_, is that correct?

Comment: `Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0, of: 
date3am, direction: .backward)` does *not* add or subtract 4 hours from `date3am` - even if it *seems* like that's what it should do. It returns a new Date object that represents the same *calendar* day, with the new **Time** - so, your result of "4 am on July 1" *is* correct.

Comment: @DonMag: I don't want to subtract 4 hours, I want to set the time to 4:00. But I don't want to go to the next 4am, but backwards to the previous one (which would be 1 day ago, if run from 0:00-3:59)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. You need to use calendar method `nextDate(after date:)` as follow:

```
let date3am = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 7, day: 1, hour: 3, minute: 0, second: 0))!

if let date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: date3am, matching: DateComponents(hour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward) {
    date // "Jun 30, 2017, 4:00 AM"
    date < date3am // true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The `bySettingHour` method seems to have the same parameters as the enumeration method - but the main difference seems to be that `nextDate` is able to go backwards.